# Graphic subsystems in R

Tags: r, graphics, internals, r-grid

In the [R Internals documentation about graphics](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Graphics-Devices) (as of 2016/03/06) it is mentioned that

> Although there is provision for 24 subsystems since about 2001, currently still only two exist, ‘base’ and ‘grid’

What does it mean exactly? I understand the difference between `grid`and `graphics` subsystems but why would there be a limit on the number of alternative subsystems?

Thank you for your help.